# .NET MAUI merged dictionaries missing on Android

Tags: android, maui, resourcedictionary

I have 4 resource files that are in the Application's dictionary. Each one is in the same folder and has Build Action set to MauiXaml.

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMO3"
             x:Class="CMO3.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/CMOColors.xaml"/>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/CMOStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

With .NET MAUI running on Windows I can see all of them.
[image]

When I point Visual Studio at my Samsung S20 FE 5G, the same line of code only sees one of them.
[image]

The one that shows up is the first one: Colors.xaml that come with default MAUI projects. I could merge all of them myself but I'm mystified why MergedDictionaries isn't working on Android.

Comment: Could there be an error loading the resources themselves on Windows? Did you check the Output when starting the app?

Comment: You can check the [Merge resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries#merge-resource-dictionaries), these resource actually provide for the Winui platform.